# CUPS wont´t print

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

When I try to print using command `lp -d Printer file`
It writes : `request id is Printer (1 file(s))`and nothing else happens. 
How to start printing ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Ubuntu? How have you connected the printer (what kind of printer?) to the computer? Have you set up the printer through the CUPS interface ( http://localhost:631 )? What does the command `lpstat -t` tell you? On my working system:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ lpstat -t
scheduler is running
system default destination: deskjet
device for deskjet: hp:/usb/Deskjet_6980_series?serial=MY8962R2XF04YX
device for envelope: usb://HP/Deskjet%206980%20series?serial=MY8962R2XF04YX
device for Labels8163: hp:/usb/Deskjet_6980_series?serial=MY8962R2XF04YX
deskjet accepting requests since Mon 01 Apr 2019 09:46:55 AM EDT
envelope accepting requests since Thu 28 Mar 2019 12:27:11 PM EDT
Labels8163 accepting requests since Thu 03 Jan 2019 06:26:41 PM EST
printer deskjet is idle.  enabled since Mon 01 Apr 2019 09:46:55 AM EDT
printer envelope disabled since Thu 28 Mar 2019 12:27:11 PM EDT -
    Paused
printer Labels8163 disabled since Thu 03 Jan 2019 06:26:41 PM EST -
    Paused
```

walt@bat:~(0)$

Comment: Sorry, I have figured it out just now. It seems, I somehow added two printers and was sending the text to the bad one. Thanks for Answer :-)

Comment: Just one more question. Is there any way to add printer using only terminal ? For case I had non-graphics environment  ?

Comment: "Just one more question." NO. You may not ask new questions an a comment. If you have another question, click on the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. New questions asked in comments aren't indexed, and are hard for other people to find. While it might be possible to add a printer from the command line, this isn't the way to ask.